# UIPanGestureRecognizer action method not called in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uipangesturerecognizer

I have set a pan gesture to an imageView, though it's action method never being called in swift 3.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureHandler(panGesture:)))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
imageview.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

the action method:

```
@objc func panGestureHandler(panGesture recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try once removing `@objc` from function definition

Comment: already tried that... didn't work

Comment: regarding removal of @objc : old joke about DEC field circus engineer applies

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems dumb, but after debugging I've noticed that the imageView's userInteractionEnabled is set to false.

After adding this line `imageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` everything seems to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use a function handler for you rUIPanGestureRecognizer like this.

> ```
> func panGestureHandler(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
> }
> ```